# AllowAnonymous skipped over with OpenIdDict 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, openiddict

I am using OpenIdDict 3.0 and it works great however I have one controller that uses the AllowAnonymous attribute and I am still receiving "The request was rejected because the access token was missing". I am assuming it could be something with the ordering in my Startup which makes it not get hit in the pipeline but I am not sure.  Here is my startup class:

```
 public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }


 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }).AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(WebConfig.ConnectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("X.Api.DataAccess"));
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
            .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
            });

            services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                    .UseDbContext<MyDbContext>();
                })
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                     .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                     .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

                    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                    .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                   scopes.
                    options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.OpenId, Scopes.OfflineAccess);

                    // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                    options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                           .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                    options.UseAspNetCore()
                    .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();
                })
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
                options.UseLocalServer();

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });




        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is actually "normal": when you set `DefaultAuthenticateScheme`, the authentication middleware (aka `app.UseAuthentication()`) - which is usually added very early in the ASP.NET Core pipeline - automatically invokes the corresponding authentication handler to populate `HttpContext.User`.

This mechanism always happens independently of whether your MVC actions are decorated with `[Authorize]` or `[AllowAnonymous]`. If OpenIddict cannot find the access token in the `Authorization` header, it logs an error and tells the authentication stack it couldn't provide the `AuthenticateResult` it requested.

If your MVC actions are decorated with `[Authorize]`, the authentication stack will ask OpenIddict to return a 401 challenge (unless `[AllowAnonymous]` is used).

That said, while it doesn't prevent things from working normally, I agree it may be an important source of noise, so I'll consider removing this log message. I opened https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/941 to track that.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to get rid of the DB context creation using `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. But it doesn't work that way. So I had to create my own replacement for `AuthenticationMiddleware` and add the necessary paths to the exceptions.

Now step by step.

**First**. Create middleware:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _nextWithoutAuth;
    private readonly AuthenticationMiddleware _nextWithAuth;

    private List<PathString> _withoutAuth = new List<PathString>
    {
        "/url/1", "/url/2"
    };

    public CustomAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
        IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _nextWithoutAuth = next;
        _nextWithAuth = ActivatorUtilities
            .CreateInstance<AuthenticationMiddleware>(sp, next);
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var path = context.Request.Path.HasValue ? 
            context.Request.Path.Value : null;

        var withoutAuth = context.Request.Path.HasValue
            && _withoutAuth.Any(it => path.StartsWith(it, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (withoutAuth)
        {
            await _nextWithoutAuth.Invoke(context);
        }
        else
        {
            await _nextWithAuth.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second**. Fill array `_withoutAuth` with required values.

**Third**. In Startup.cs replace `app.UseAuthentication();` with `app.UseMiddleware<CustomAuthenticationMiddleware>();`.

p.s. I use .net core 2.1

p.s.s. I assume you can improve my solution if get all controllers and their methods with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and than add them into `_withoutAuth` array.